# Redis server fails to start in docker

Tags: redis, docker, containers

I have a docker image 'redis_image' that installed redis in it. After I run a container as:

```
docker run --name test_redis -it redis_image bash
```

the redis server can start normally in the container using '/etc/init.d/redis start'.

But if I run the container with `--net=host` option, the redis server will fail to start in the container, it says "Starting redis-server: could not open session [Failed]". Is the problem related to the `--net=host` configuration when I run the container? Thanks.

Comment: Since `/etc/init.d/redis start` succeeds in starting the redis service, replace `bash` in your `docker run` command with that command and see if it helps. Also you'll need to provide more info about the image. Is it required to create a container with `--net=host`? Can't you map its port to host instead of using that option?

Comment: @Dharmit, I think the only problem is the use of '--net'=host option, without it, everything works fine. The reason to use that is just my mentor want to use that and expose all the container's ports, but we have problem with this

Comment: if it's about exposing the container ports, why not use `-p` option with `docker run` command? `--net=host` is not recommended as host network configuration could then be controlled from container!

Comment: @Dharmit, you are right. The `--net=host` is not recommended, as it is not safe. Thank you for your help!